# Sub-subdomain getting redirected to main domain

Tags: multisite, redirect, htaccess, subdomains

I'm working on a multisite network.

I intend to make it a subdomain based network but cant seem to make it work because of the redirects.
The main multisite network resides under app.trainergoesonline.com

So subsequent sites should go under site1.app.trainergoesonline.com, site2.app.trainergoesonline.com and so on.
So far any installation I've done, I havent been able to access them as they keep redirecting to the root domain "trainergoesonline.com"

Following are the lines i included in the wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'app.trainergoesonline.com' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

And following are the .htaccess rules for wordpress [all boilerplate]

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

 RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]

 RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]

 RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I've looked far and wide across the internet but unable to find any valid direction to solve this redirection issue.

A couple of sites i tried to create are test2.trainergoesonline.com test10.trainergoesonline.com
They all get redirected to the root domain

I look at this community with great hope!

Comment: Just to clarify, there's nothing in your `.htaccess` that is causing the redirection (as you say, it's "all boilerplate"). What status code are you seeing on the redirection? 301? 302?30x?

Comment: @MrWhite I actually dont see any status code (or might not know where to look for one). It straight up goes to the homepage of the root directory in a flash, no questions asked.

**EDIT:** I just checked the network tab and it shows a 301 before going to the root domain

Comment: "I just checked the network tab and it shows a 301 before going to the root domain" - If you then click on that request in the network tab, it will show you the HTTP response headers that are sent back (also make sure the "disable cache" checkbox is checked at the top). Do you see mention of "WordPress"? That will indicate that it's WP itself initiating the redirect and not Apache (or proxy) etc.

Comment: @MrWhite I got into the response headers and was able to retrieve the following
`HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 07 Jan 2021 18:20:50 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 162
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://test10.trainergoesonline.com/
Host-Header: 8441280b0c35cbc1147f8ba998a563a7
X-HTTPS-Enforce: 1
X-Proxy-Cache-Info: DT:1
`
2nd Response header in the next comment.

Comment: @MrWhite contd from previous comment, Response header #2

`GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: test10.trainergoesonline.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9
`

Comment: So as per that, it seems it was not initiated by WP itself, its probably nginx doing this, but I cant be sure. In the initiator though it says "Other"

Comment: "its probably nginx doing this" - That is what it looks like. You seem to have a front-end caching proxy (Nginx) in front of Apache (assuming you are actually using Apache and your `.htaccess` file is indeed "working").